# Cannot be Parameterized with arguments Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra

```
package com.ksfe.auditlog.repository;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;

import com.ksfe.auditlog.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerRepository extends CassandraRepository<Customer> {

}
```

---

in which the error shows as 
Incorrect number of arguments for type CassandraRepository; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Comment: i followed the below link    https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-mvc/angular-4-spring-boot-cassandra-crud-example

Comment: do you use the same versions that are used in this article?

Comment: what version do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`public interface CustomerRepository extends CassandraRepository<Customer>`

to

`public interface CustomerRepository extends CassandraRepository<Customer,Integer>`

by adding id parameter also.

NOTE : Integer/Long depends on the ID type.

Comment: When i give like you said it triggrring an error in cotrollerr just like below............Customer customerData = customerRepository.findOne(BasicMapId.id("id", id)); in which the the findOne is not taking or happening error upon it

Comment: Also check this link it shows its ok to given as Customer in repository.  followed this site but it triggered me an errer as i described

Comment: https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-mvc/angular-4-spring-boot-cassandra-crud-example